# Does proxy-auto-detect work in CefSharp.Wpf?

Tags: proxy, cefsharp

I am trying too get CefSharp to auto resolve proxy settings. Chrome can do it. You can even change the proxy setting while Chrome is running and Chrome will react on it.

I am using proxy-auto-detect. But it's not working
Can anyone confirm that its works in CefSharp [v.63.0.3](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/releases/tag/v63.0.3)

```
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-auto-detect", "1");
```

The only way I can get proxy settings to work is if I set it my self

```
 settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-pac-url", autoConfigUrl);
 settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", proxy.ProxyAddress.Replace(' ', ';'));
```

[Link to proxy settings for Cef](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage)

Comment: CefSharp is just a wrapper see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#cefsharp-vs-chromium-embedded-frameworkcef

Comment: CEF has it's own forum at http://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php

Comment: Thanks I know its a wrapper I checked out the repo and have it running on my pc. I just wants to know if any one can confirm that proxy-auto-detect is working

Comment: Test with the CEF sample application, ask on ceforum.